# OLED дисплей модуль Перевернуть изображение на 180 градусов

Tags: arduino, oledb, display

Делаю проект, с экранном на ардуине. Физически нет возможности развернуть дисплей. как это сделать программно?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SeeedOLED.h>


void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  SeeedOled.init();  //initialze SEEED OLED display

  SeeedOled.clearDisplay();          //clear the screen and set start position to top left corner
  SeeedOled.setNormalDisplay();      //Set display to normal mode (i.e non-inverse mode)
  SeeedOled.setPageMode();           //Set addressing mode to Page Mode
  SeeedOled.setTextXY(0,0);          //Set the cursor to Xth Page, Yth Column  
  SeeedOled.putString("Hello World!"); //Print the String

}

void loop()
{

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем спасибо за помощь, разобрался две команды решают, дисплей имеет возможность отображать все по вертикали и горизонтали, и библиотеку править не нужно, просто принудетельно даем эти команды вот готовый код.

```
//#include <Wire.h>
#include <SeeedOLED.h>

//***
#include <Wire.h>

//**************функцыя для принудительных команд напрямую дисплею
void oledCommand(int comm) {

 Wire.beginTransmission(0x3C);//Начинаем передачу команд устройству с адресом 0x3C.

 Wire.write(0x00);//Сообщаем дисплею, что следующее передаваемое значение - команда.

 Wire.write(comm);//Передаем команду.

 Wire.endTransmission();//Завершаем передачу данных.

}


void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  //************Перевернуть все
  oledCommand(0xA0);//0xA1 отражение по горизонтали, для отображения справа налево необходимо использовать команду 0xA0
  oledCommand(0xC0);//0xC8 отражение по вертикали, 0xC0 для переворота изображения по вертикали.



  SeeedOled.init();  //initialze SEEED OLED display

  SeeedOled.clearDisplay();          //clear the screen and set start position to top left corner
  SeeedOled.setNormalDisplay();      //Set display to normal mode (i.e non-inverse mode)
  SeeedOled.setPageMode();           //Set addressing mode to Page Mode
  SeeedOled.setTextXY(0,0);          //Set the cursor to Xth Page, Yth Column  
  SeeedOled.putString("Hello World!"); //Print the String

}

void loop()
{

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просмотрел библиотеку SeeedOLED, далее пришёл к документации на драйвер SSD1308. Боюсь, что простого решения развернуть изображение нет. Силами библиотеки и графического драйвера это сделать невозможно. Как вариант решения - рендеринг изображения в память контроллера, поворот и далее вывод построено на экран.

Comment: На любом дисплее должен быть поворот/разворот изображения. Может в библиотеке это не реализовано, либо реализовано неявно. Попробуйте с другой библиотекой.

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу только два варианта:

1. Формировать в памяти изображение, как уже советовал Roman Ozhegov
2. Полностью переписать библиотеку, изменив в ней:

   - Массив знакогенерации. Нужно изменить порядок байт в каждом символе и порядок бит в каждом байте
   - Команду установки координат
   - Команду вывода текста, выводить символы в обратном порядке

Comment: Спасибо, но если уже править библиотеку так жёстко, наверно проще заново свою реализовать.